# How to get cocoa pods to work?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa

I have installed cocoapods. I've done everything that I've seen online, yet I can never successfully import a 3rd party framework into my project. I have tried many, many times--at least 20 probably, and have not once been able to successfully do this. Take for example, this library: https://github.com/uacaps/PageMenu

I added the podfile, I ran "pod install", that worked, I opened up the workspace and not the original project, I added the framework under "linked frameworks and libraries." But it still says "No such module Page Menu." It does this for every single pod that I try to install. What am I doing wrong? From what I've read everyone seems to think they are so easy to install. And they are, problem is they just never work once I do install them. Is there some missing step that everyone else knows about that I don't? I have looked under build settings and I've read something about changing the linker flags, but I couldn't figure out how to do that. I have tried installing the library manually and that didn't work either. Could it be that something is just wrong with my Xcode? I've been having this problem for a few months, and it has stayed consistent since I updated my Xcode recently. Does anyone have any idea what this could be?

edit: link to Podfile photo:

http://i58.tinypic.com/2lc2zqb.png

Comment: Could you post what your Podfile looks like?

Comment: Try to read tutorials how to import cocoapods. There are bunch of them out there. Yes you are doing it wrong and misses simple steps. Google import cocoapods.

Comment: What simple steps am I missing? I've read many tutorials, watched them on youtube, read other stack overflow questions, and still have this problem. cocoa pods is already installed successfully. and @doctorBroctor I updated my question with the photo

Comment: @joey Are you using `Objective-C`? Try this: `#import <PageMenu/PageMenu-Swift.h>`

Answer (score 1):

First,make sure that you have something like this in your PodFile (same folder as your xcode proj)

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'PageMenu'
```

then cd to the directory and do `pod install` in terminal.

I am assuming that you are using swift. Build the project. Go to your report navigator.

EDIT:: Do open the proj using xcworkspace instead of xcodeproj

[image: Go to your report navigator]

You should see something like this.

[image]

This tells you what you have to add in your bridging header.
To create a bridging header, create a random objective c file (with cocoa touch class). XCode will ask you if you want to create bridging header.
[image]

Select yes, then delete the files you just created. Next, go to the generated bridging header file. Add in

```
 // this header should be based on the name you see in report navigator.
 #import <PageMenu/PageMenu-Swift.h>
```

Answer (score -1):

Look, Calm Down..
I had the same problem.Didnt give up.try doing this as well,worked for me

1. create new project
2. close xcode
3. go to target folder pop init
4. open -a Xcode Podfile-uncomment platform -pod 'PageMenu' ( I typed this outside target this time/not like the usual way typing it inside target- do/ ,save and close)
5. open xcodeworkspace and Type - import PageMenu -( still says unresolved module )
   Now Build ..

(worked for me, It somehow works with clean or Build i suppose ,so try both)